# Having trouble with jQuery changing the background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make jQuery dynamically change the background image by pulling the src attribute from the image tag (img#backSwitch) on the page (which i will make randomly pull from an array in php later), and change the div.background-image element's background-image property value to whatever the src attribute's value is. my console.log is working just fine, i would like to think what i am doing in jQuery is fine as well, but clearly I'm doing something wrong or overlooking a mistake that isn't showing an error. Any help would be great!

Here is my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="background-image"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="img/ped4.jpg" id="backSwitch" alt="Pedestal" />
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

HERE IS MY jQuery

```
(function() {

    var backSwitch = $('#backSwitch').attr('src'),
        theURL = 'http://staging.youknowphabo.com/';


    $('.background-image').css({backgroundImage: 'url('+theURL+backSwitch+');'});

    console.log(theURL+backSwitch);

})();
```

HERE IS MY CSS

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400);

.background-image {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}


.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
} 

.content img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: try: `$('.background-image').css("background-image", "url("+theURL+backSwitch+")");  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is a typo:

```
$('.background-image').css({backgroundImage: 'url('+theURL+backSwitch+')'});
```

Try removing the semicolon from the CSS url property.

You could also write it like this:

```
$('.background-image').css({'background-image': 'url('+theURL+backSwitch+')'});
```

Comment: $('.background-image').css({backgroundImage: 'url('+theURL+backSwitch+')'});  The "backgroundImage" within the object needs to be background-image instead.  so... $('.background-image').css({'background-image': 'url('+theURL+backSwitch+')'});

Comment: @user2278120 I think backgroundImage should work too: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/juesdn9m/)

Comment: Removing the `;` worked for me too. Note, you could also use     `$('.background-image').css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + theURL + backSwitch + ')');` instead.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Both should work, right? I used the one the OP used, but actually tested first to see if it was "background-image" instead but both seemed ok.

Comment: @Alvaro Yup, I tested your solution, +1, and it worked for me. I was just adding alternative way in the theme, "There's always another way to do it" :)

Comment: @ChrisHappy great, thanks for the feedback, Ill include the alternative :)

Comment: Thanks! i completely overlooked the fact that i put a semicolon there. Simple typo.